# Is there a way to get persistent battery charge data?

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, battery-life

I have a laptop with Ubuntu 10.04 and would like to know if there's a way to get persistent battery charge data.  The current setup erases the battery charge data (available visually via gnome battery icon in top menu bar) on every reboot.  If I can discover where this info is stored I could sample it with cron and build a history file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my laptop I can find the data in `/proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state`.

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/state
present:                 yes
capacity state:          ok
charging state:          charged
present rate:            0 mA
remaining capacity:      4290 mAh
present voltage:         12541 mV
```